# VB6 TCP IP Communication without Doevents or subclassing

Tags: vb6, winsock, winsockets

What I need to happen with a VB6 application I maintain is the following.

1. Establish a connection to a known address and port over a Ethernet
   network.
2. Send a request
3. Wait for a response.

I tried using WinSock and Winsock replacement but they all rely in one form or another the messaging loop inherent in various Windows application. I don't know enough about the Winsock API how to implement the above algorithm in VB6 (or in any other language.

My application is a VB6 CAD/CAM software that controls metal cutting machines over a dedicated Ethernet network. The software has been maintain for 20 years and we developed several driver for different types of motion controllers. To date the API for these motion controllers consist of

1. Opening a connection to the hardware
2. Sending a request to the hardware (for example Position of an axis)
3. Waiting for a response (usually occurs in milliseconds).

Some of these controller work over a Ethernet Network but until now I never had to directly interact with the ports. I used the company supplied libraries to handle things. And they work in the way I mentioned above and throw a timeout error if a response doesn't occur in some defined time.

The problem with Winsock is that I have to insert DoEvents to get it a respond. This causes havoc with how we handle multi-tasking in our VB6 application. The replacement like CSocketMaster use subclassing which also cause havoc with our multi-tasking.

So any help on how to use the Winsock API or a third party dll that can do what I need to do as outlined above. I wouldn't be asking if I haven't seen other motion control do what I want to do.

Comment: Have you considered running the requests asynchronously via an out-of-process server (AX EXE)? Having this activity on a separate thread from the main (only) VB6 thread seems like just what such components were intended for.

Comment: Multitasking in VB6 - wowza - that's impressive. That is one difficult accomplishment. Congrats. You can definitely use Winsock API but I don't know how you're going to avoid using DoEvents. Maybe some type of polling mechanism that checks for a file existing? It's going to take some kind of hack though

Comment: @Jim Mack Yeah but like with Subclasses Active EXE had their own set of issue most regarding cleanly shutting down. We had a few back when I fire built the software around 2001 but over the long haul there are too many glitches where the thing doesn't shut down properly so we got rid of all of them.

I have to stress, there are other people, like Galil Motion Control, that do what I need for their own hardware. But the motion controller my bosses want to use doesn't supply that. Only the ability to listen and respond to TCP/IP ports is provided. So I have to do what the Galil libraries do.

Comment: @RSConley: [here](https://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=34493&lngWId=1) is a project with an in-deep explanation of the Winsock API, maybe it will help You with that part of Your question. BTW, give a look at how `TCP_NODELAY` works.

Comment: @RSConley: though I am aware that You question clearly states that You need to use TCP, may I ask You why You don't use UDP? No worries, I am just curious.

Comment: @deblocker, good question, UDP is an option and we may use it. I didn't bring it up because the root problem is the same in regards to VB6, Winsock's event driven design. I could be misreading the documentation about UDP and Winsock, so a fuller answer in regards to UDP and the Winsock control would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think it is rare for it to be appropriate to do networking
>   synchronously, however this isn't networking in the traditional sense.
>   This is a wire from a PC to a controller. This is like a string
>   between two cans. In this case with a large old program, the most
>   appropriate approach is the one that works the best and is the easiest
>   to maintenance. **< /end2cents >**

If VB6 + Winsock isn't working out for you, writing this in .NET and building it into a COM visible DLL for your VB6 program will fit the bill.

The example below will get you started. If you do more than the occasional call to this, it will be slow as it opens and closes the connection on each call. It should be easy to expand it to allow for reusing an open connection for back and forth communication between the PC and controller. Just be careful that you don't create a memory leak!

```
/// <summary>
/// Sends a message to the specified host:port, and waits for a response
/// </summary>
public string SendAndReceive(string host, int port, string messageToSend, int millisecondTimeout)
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new TcpClient())
        {
            client.SendTimeout = client.ReceiveTimeout = millisecondTimeout;
            // Perform connection
            client.Connect(host, port);

            if (client.Connected)
            {
                using (var stream = client.GetStream())
                {
                    // Convert the message to a byte array
                    var toSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageToSend);

                    // Send the message
                    stream.Write(toSend, 0, toSend.Length);

                    // Get a response
                    var response = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                    stream.Read(response, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

                    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(retVal);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out [VbAsyncSocket repo](https://github.com/wqweto/VbAsyncSocket) on github for pure VB6 asynchronous sockets implementation (using [`WSAAsyncSelect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741540(v=vs.85).aspx) API for sockets to post event notifications).

Contrary to it's name the class *does* support [`SyncSendArray`](https://github.com/wqweto/VbAsyncSocket/blob/master/src/cAsyncSocket.cls#L1051) and [`SyncReceiveArray`](https://github.com/wqweto/VbAsyncSocket/blob/master/src/cAsyncSocket.cls#L983) methods for synchronous operations -- without `DoEvents` but with `Timeout`s.

In the same repo there is a handy [`cWinSockRequest`](https://github.com/wqweto/VbAsyncSocket/blob/master/contrib/cWinSockRequest.cls) contributed class, that is very similar to `WinHttpRequest` object as baked into the OS. This helper class will be very familliar to you if you have experience with JSON/XML (generally RESTful services over http/https) for accessing services/devices over plain tcp/udp sockets.

Another option would be to use [`cTlsClient`](https://github.com/wqweto/VbAsyncSocket/blob/master/contrib/cTlsClient.cls) contributed class, that can connect to host/device over tcp (no udp here) and provides `ReadText`/`WriteText` and `ReadArray`/`WriteArray` (synchronous) methods. The added benefit here is that the class supports both plain unencrypted sockets and SSL encrypted channels if need be.

We are using these classes to (synchronously) access ESP/POS printers from our LOB applications. Most POS printers also provide serial (USB-to-COM) links too, so we are abstracting our access w/ connector classes -- [`SyncWaitForEvent`](https://github.com/wqweto/VbAsyncSocket/blob/master/src/cAsyncSocket.cls#L1107) over async sockets and [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025(v=vs.85).aspx) on overlapped `ReadFile`/`WriteFile` APIs (oh, the irony)

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out the answer involved implementing Allen's Suggestion.

The specific problem was communicating between two device involved in the control of a piece of machinery. The device that did the motion control is acting as a server, while the PC providing the motion data was a client.

The Ethernet network was being used in lieu of a proprietary bus interface or a RS-232/422 serial interface. So many of the considerations involved in serving up data over a widespread internet were not a factor. The network consisted of known devices residing at fixed IPs listening to specific ports.

After talking to people who make other motion control. The logic for the client turned out to be surprisingly simple.

1. Send the Data
2. Wait in a Loop for the response breaking out if it taking too long.
3. Handle any errors in the connection.

On the server side, we were lucky in that we had control over the software running on the motion controller. So there the communication loop was designed to be as fast as possible. One key point was to keep all data below 512 bytes so it is all contained in a single packet. They also took great care in priortizing the communication handler and the data structure so it can send out a response in tens of microseconds.

Another point was that in this application of dedicated clients and server that UDP is preferred over TCP as Operation Systems particularly Windows were in the habit of shutting down idle TCP Connections unexpectedly.

Because the client software is slowly transition over to the .NET framework that was another factor for implementing Allen's idea. The library discussed by @wqw worked as well.

Comment: Migrate to .NET? If You have some time, give a look here: [Real time communication with WebRTC](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#0)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using the Winsock control incorrectly.  That probably stems from a flaw in your interaction model.

Don't "send and wait" because blocking like that is your big mistake.  There is no "waiting" anyway unless you think sitting in a buzz loop is waiting.

Instead send your request and exit from that event handler.  All of your code is contained in event handlers, that's how it works.  Then as DataArrival events are raised you append the new arrived fragment to a stream buffer then scan the assembled stream for a complete response.  Then go ahead and process the response.

Handle timeouts using a Timer control that you enable after sending.  When you have assembled a completed response disable the Timer.  If the interval elapses and Timer event is raised do your error processing there.

You seem to have a particularly chatty protocol so you shouldn't have to do anything else.  For example you can just clear your stream buffer after processing a complete response, since there can't be anything else left in there anyway.

Forget "multitasking" and avoid DoEvents() calls like the plague they are.

This is *very* simple stuff.

Comment: The design of the software is such that all interactions with a machine are handled in a driver setup using ActiveX dolls. The point I need to use TCP IP is several levels away from any form or consumer of events. I build this over 20 years ago and been successfully maintaining since. As stated in the OP, other motion controllers supply libraries that does just what I describe. Now I need to implement it myself so trying to figure how they did it without Events or DoEvents requires.

Comment: Also note this is a dedicated network tied to a specific device. This not an app connected to the internet. We are using ethernet and TCP IP the same role as one would use a serial link or vendor bus (like Nechatrolink). In this case send and wait is called for. When I ask whether the emergency stop input is pushed I need to now not later. And if I don't get the response in the specified time then a error is thrown as the communication is not working properly. This is fifth motion control we implemented in the 35 years we been in business.